# DependencyProperty bool in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a problem with a DependencyProperty in a UserControl. My control exposes two Dependencyproperties, a bool and a string. The string property works, but the bool doesn't. I get no errors, but changes aren't reflected either way.

I define the property like this:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IncludeSubdirectories",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DirectorySelect),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true }
        );

public bool IncludeSubdirectories
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty, value); }
}
```

In the XAML for the user control i bind to the property like this:

```
<CheckBox
    Name="IncludeSubdirectoriesCheckbox"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeSubdirectories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    Include subfolders</CheckBox>
```

And when i use the control i bind to the properties like this:

```
<Controls:DirectorySelect
    Directory="{Binding Directory}"
    IncludeSubdirectories="{Binding WatchSubDirs}"/>
```

"Directory" is the string property that works just fine. I bind to them both in the same way, but i just can't make the bool work.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: How you see that changes are not reflected?? Have you tried set breakpoints in `WatchSubDirs` not `IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty` itself? Is `WatchSubDirs` DP or simple property?

Comment: VS doesn't signal at compile time, but prints log information on Output window of Visual Studio. There is always written something. Among all other things you should find an error on failed binding, failed conversion or whatever...

Comment: I didn't know about the status messages in the output window. That helps a lot :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try chaning the binding with your user control to an element binding. Before you do be sure to give your userControl a name.

Then change:

```
     IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeSubdirectories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

To something like this:

```
     IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeSubdirectories, ElementName="<UserControlName>", Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Another sanity check you can perform is to make sure the type owner for IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty' is correct.

Comment: That did it.

The problem was that the checkbox in my usercontrol was being bound to the datacontext in the window where i used my control, not it's own properties. The wrong datacontext had a property of the same name as in my usercontrol (Directory), so the binding accidentally worked with that property, but not IncludeSubdirectories.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try this to find out what goes wrong

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty IncludeSubdirectoriesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IncludeSubdirectories",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DirectorySelect),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIncludeSubdirectoriesPropertyChanged)) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true }
        );

privatestaticvoid OnIncludeSubdirectoriesPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  // make a breakpoint here
}
```

debug bindings

```
<CheckBox Name="IncludeSubdirectoriesCheckbox"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IncludeSubdirectories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">Include subfolders</CheckBox>
```

and

```
<Controls:DirectorySelect Directory="{Binding Directory}" IncludeSubdirectories="{Binding WatchSubDirs, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
```

you must include

```
<Window xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase" />
```

also change WPF Trace Settings at Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window
to Data Binding = Warning

now look at the ouput window what happens

hope this helps